# Labelling left and right names on a line, in a .mss file?

Tags: postgis, carto, labeling, mapnik

I am currently working with project.mml and associated .mss files.  I am looking at replacing OSM admin labels with a secondary source and I am wondering how Carto does the labeling along the lines labeled by

```
#admin-text[zoom > 11] {
  text-name: "[name]";
  text-face-name: @book-fonts;
  text-fill: @admin-boundaries;
  text-halo-radius: @standard-halo-radius;
  text-halo-fill: @standard-halo-fill;
  text-placement: line;
  text-clip: true;
  text-vertical-alignment: middle;
  text-dy: -10;
```

My understanding (being new to this), `text-dy` is the offset, but I am wondering how it knows to display the labels correctly on the left or right side.  I assume that there are multiple OSM boundary lines overlapping and depending on the direction of the line then the label appears -10 offset.

The data that I want to use, has a left and a right name attribute.  Therefore I assume that I could add to separate labels, 1 for the left with a -10 offset and 1 for the right with a +10 offset in theory.

What are Carto or OSM left and right naming conventions?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this by adding 2 text layers in the project.mml file as below (and the same for left name)

```
{
        "name": "bnd_lines_right_text",
        "srs-name": "3395",
        "geometry": "linestring",
        "class": "",
        "srs": "+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs",
        "Datasource": {
          "estimate_extent": "false",
          "extent": "-20037507.843,-30198185.170,20037507.843,30198185.170",
          "table": "(select wkb_geometry, right_name, admin_level, type from osm_bnd_lines ORDER BY admin_level DESC) AS bnd_lines_right_text",
          "geometry_field": "wkb_geometry",
          "srid": "3395",
          "type": "postgis",
          "key_field": "",
          "dbname": "osm_bdy_test",
          "host": "ximena",
          "user": "postgres"
        },
        "extent": [
          -180,
          -90,
          180,
          90
        ],
        "id": "admin-low-zoom",
        "properties": {
          "maxzoom": 10,
          "minzoom": 4
        },
        "advanced": {}
      },
```

Then adding the following to the mss file

```
#bnd_lines_left_text {
  text-name: "[left_name]";
  text-face-name: @book-fonts;
  text-fill: @admin-boundaries;
  text-halo-radius: @standard-halo-radius;
  text-halo-fill: @standard-halo-fill;
  text-placement: line;
  text-clip: true;
  text-vertical-alignment: middle;
  text-dy: 10;
}

 #bnd_lines_right_text {
  text-name: "[right_name]";
  text-face-name: @book-fonts;
  text-fill: @admin-boundaries;
  text-halo-radius: @standard-halo-radius;
  text-halo-fill: @standard-halo-fill;
  text-placement: line;
  text-clip: true;
  text-vertical-alignment: middle;
  text-dy: -10;
}
```

Seems to work very well.